# Getting the x-axis labels of dendrogram after hierachical clustering

Tags: python, scipy, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I am following all the codes in this [tutorial](https://www.jcchouinard.com/hierarchical-clustering/), I want to get the labels in the x-axis as it has been shown on the dendrogram figure. How we can do it?

Here is my code:

```
linkage_results = linkage(all_vals19k_god_glove, method='ward', metric='euclidean' )
linkage_labels = fcluster(linkage_results, 3,  criterion='maxclust')
 
dn = dendrogram(linkage_results, labels=all_lbls )
plt.title('Dendrogram')
plt.show()
plt.savefig('./original_glove_dendrogram_results.pdf')
```

`all_vals19k_god_glove` is a 200*300 numpy array which I want to apply clustering on (200 samples, eaching having 300 dimensions) and `all_labels` are each samples label name.

After clustering, I want to get the label names on the x-axis based on the order of clustering. I would like to know how can I do that.

Result of HCA:

[image]

In other words, I want to sort my other data based on results of this HCA. That is why I need to figure out the order on the x-axis...